# Selecting points from intersecting an arbitrary (non-database) polygon with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, ruby

Determining a polygon as follows, and the points to check against, in ruby

```
@poly = GEOFACTORY.polygon(@line_string1)
@locations = Location.all
@valid_locations = Location.order("id").where("st_intersects(ST_GeomFromText(@poly), @locations.lonlat)").all
```

`@poly` returns  `POLYGON ((9.0395777869 45.6141806128, 9.0395777869 45.3141806128, 9.3395777869 45.3141806128, 9.3395777869 45.6141806128, 9.0395777869 45.6141806128))`
 and Location.lonlat is defined with `:srid => 3785`.  Similar queries that check against database column data run properly, however this query states

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "poly" does not exist
```

Is it possible to query postGIS with arbitrary data?  If so, where is this query off track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not interpolating the Ruby variables into the string you pass to Postgres. In other words, the WHERE query doesn't know what "@poly" means, because it doesn't have access to your running Ruby environment.

Either:

1. Interpolate the variables into the string, e.g. `#{@poly}`, or
2. Use placeholders

How exactly you do this will depend on the syntax of the ORM you're using, but you haven't specified what it is (ActiveRecord?). It may be more of a general Ruby question than a GIS-specific one.

Comment: I should have caught that, but I guess I'm getting tripped up between ruby, rgeo and straight sql.  The interpolation jump started (via ActiveRecord), however PG did not like it too much, pointing at the space between lon and lat (chich I find curious as that is the syntax normally):  `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "45.6141806128"
LINE 1: ...es"  WHERE (st_intersects((POLYGON ((9.0395777869 45.6141806...`

Comment: Removing `ST_GeomFromText` does not alter the error.

Comment: `st_intersects((POLYGON ((9.0395777869...` isn't valid SQL - it should be `ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON(9.0395777869 45.614...` and so on. It would help if you could post the full SQL being generated.

Comment: Thanks Richard.  I happend to have picked up on the single quote matter a while ago, viewing good examples.  I did not have the CAPS correct.  That did not impact the next hurdle `PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries
: SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations"  WHERE (ST_intersects(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((9.0395777869 45.6141806128, [...] 9.0395777869 45.6141806128))'), locations.lonlat))`

Comment: `"ST_intersects(ST_GeomFromText('#{@poly}', 3785), locations.lonlat)"` *for anyone who is following* is the proper string for the where command in rails